# CSS container scrollbar - Why aren't my items staying within content size and making a scrollbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am able to display the data I want and my alignment are close. but I'm currently facing a problem

My issue is my top post data isn't displaying a scrollbar

I thought adding `min-w-0 max-h-full overflow-y-scroll` would solve the problem.
Currently, with the default 20 post it stretches my container instead of making it scrollable

Here is a link to a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-cache-bix3k?file=/src/Toppost.js) with my code sample. Any explanation is appreciated

P.S I'm using tailwind.

```html
<div className="min-w-0 max-h-full overflow-y-scroll">
  <ContentHeader title="Top Post" /> {posts.map(post => (
  <div key={post.id}>
    <div className='px-10 my-4 py-4 bg-white border border-8 border-gray-400 rounded-lg border-solid'>
      <div className='flex justify-between'>
        <span className='font-light text-black text-lg font-semibold'>@{post.username}</span>
        <span className='font-medium rounded ml-56'> {moment(post.postDate).format(('L'))}. {moment(post.postDate).format(('LT'))}</span>
        <a className="font-extrabold rounded text-3xl text-blue-600" href={post.postUrl} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          <BsArrowUpRight />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-2">
        <p className='mt-2 text-xl text-gray-600'>{post.textContent}</p>
      </div>
      <SocialAction likeCount={post.likeCount} commentCount={post.commentCount} sentiment={post.sentiment} />
    </div>
  </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

[image]

This is how it should look with a scrollbar :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you wanted to use `max-h-screen` instead of `max-h-full`. `max-h-full` gives the element `height: 100%` which in your case, does nothing. `max-h-screen` gives `height: 100vh` so it's actually getting height.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-62186352-lwj1n?file=/src/Toppost.js

In the example, I've added `before` and `after` texts so you could see the scrollbar.

Comment: Very much appreciated, also your answer gave me more insight on the difference.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck.